# How to install OpenCPU?

Tags: r, opencpu

I'd like to try OpenCPU in my own server. Official Installation Manual linked from https://public.opencpu.org/pages/download.html is not found.

Where can I get install instruction?

Comment: ServerFault would probably be a better suit for this question.

Comment: I think this is a question for @jeroen.  (Hopefully this comment pings the [right one](http://stackoverflow.com/users/318752/jeroen).) Otherwise, maybe you could [raise an issue](https://github.com/jeroenooms/opencpu/issues) on github

Comment: While I believe that the question is diffuse and strictly does not belong here, Jeroen's reply is worth being kept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The new version of OpenCPU, which hasn't officially been released yet, runs locally as well:

```
library(devtools); 
install_github("opencpu", "jeroenooms")
library(opencpu)
```

Note that you need a recent version of `httpuv`.

For now you can also have a look at the [API doc](https://github.com/jeroenooms/opencpu/blob/master/api.txt), the [opencpu.js](https://github.com/jeroenooms/opencpu.js) javascript library and the [cloud server](https://github.com/jeroenooms/opencpu-deb#readme).