# Unable to install opencpu through CRAN

Tags: r, linux, ubuntu, rstudio, opencpu

I have updated to Rstudio 1.1.383 (for Ubuntu 16.04 Xenial AMD64) and R 3.4.2. 
Am trying to install opencpu package to test standalone R-code before pushing to the cloudserver version of opencpu, but without any luck. I am following the instructions from: [OpenCPU instructions](https://www.opencpu.org/download.html)

> > trying URL 'http://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/opencpu_2.0.5.tar.gz' Content
> >     type 'application/x-gzip' length 372977 bytes (364 KB)
> >     ================================================== downloaded 364 KB
>
> - installing *source* package ‘opencpu’ ...
>     ** package ‘opencpu’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
>     ** R
>     ** data
>     *** moving datasets to lazyload DB
>     ** inst
>     ** preparing package for lazy loading Error in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]) :
>     namespace ‘evaluate’ 0.10 is being loaded, but >= 0.10.1 is required
>     ERROR: lazy loading failed for package ‘opencpu’
> - removing ‘/home/vmpdc/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4/opencpu’ Warning in install.packages :   installation of package ‘opencpu’ had
>     non-zero exit status

Have tried using:

```
install.packages("opencpu",repos="http://cran.rstudio.com/")
```

and

```
install.packages("opencpu",repos="http://cran.cnr.Berkeley.edu/")
```

but no difference.

Not sure if this has any effect, but have installed the cloud server version of the opencpu on the same ubuntu box (which is under apache2).

I was able to follow the instructions from here[How to install OpenCPU](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18029259/how-to-install-opencpu), which uses the github link (though did get an error for

> configuration failed for package protolite

- protobuf-compiler is not installed in my system for R3.4.2)

Not sure what to make of the namespace 'evaluate' error, though.

Comment: Jeoren's suggestion did the trick. Incidentally, following his other somewhat related [suggestion](https://github.com/jeroen/protolite/issues/4) on github, I did: `sudo apt-get install protobuf-compiler` and that took care of the protolite error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It says the `evaluate` package is outdated. Try this:

```
update.packages(ask = FALSE)
```

The `opencpu` package requires the latest version of the `evaluate` package.